# In Groovy, how does the method city() print without a print method

Tags: groovy

I'm learning groovy sql. And I have saw the following code:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(...)
def bldr = new MarkupBuilder()
bldr.weather {
  sql.eachRow('select * from weather'){
    city(name:it.city,temperature:it.temperature)
  }
}
```

The database table name is **weather**, columns: **city** and **tempertature**.

When I execute above script, my console print the weather content in XML format.

That what confused me is: why console prints XML without **print()** method.

Comment: How are you running this script? on groovy shell?

Comment: @Rao yes.I code in Grails Tool Suite——a eclipse groovy tool.And Run by "Alt+Shift+X  G"

Comment: I think I can find answer in MarkupBuilder source code,but I can not find the source code in package groovy.xml. And my original question is how can I input the xml content into a file using above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run groovy code in console it by default returns and prints the last executed statement. E.g. if the script is:

```
def l = [1, 2, 3, ]
```

The output will be:

```
groovy> def l = [1, 2, 3, ] 

Result: [1, 2, 3]
```

even though there's no `print` statement in the script.

To serialize generated XML to file you need an instance of `Writer`

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def sql =  Sql.newInstance(...)

def writer = new FileWriter('weather.xml')
def bldr = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

bldr.weather {
  sql.each{
    city(name:it.city,temperature:it.temperature)
  }
}
```

Comment: @jianbo.fan if you found my answer helpful, please accept it :)

Comment: sorry,I didn't know how the answer should be accepted before.now I have knew and accepted it.